# Trying to get into the Iframe which has only src property in it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

```
<div class="survey-container survey-container--normal">
<iframe src="https://survey.beta.savanta.com?&amp;id=b3f708008f&amp;id2=01a424da&amp;idp=test-efcd18e447b042adbecd987a9a76ae2d"></iframe></div>
```

Code looks like this
I am trying to get into this `iframe`
Tried everything which can be possible but couldn't get in

Tried with Xpath,
Tried with CSS Selector,
Tried with Loop

There are several button inside the `iframe` which I am trying to click but since I can't get in I am not able to click or proceed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count how many IFRAMEs are there in the entire DOM. Then use the below XPath expression:

```
(//iframe)[1]
```

If there is only one IFRAME then just use the above expression. If there are 2 iframes, and the desired iframe is the second one then expression should be: `(//iframe)[2]` and so on.

Full code:

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//iframe)[1]")))
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Once you have performed all actions within `IFRAME`, to come out of it use the below code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Tried not working, and there is only one Iframe

Comment: `Tried not working` - this won't help. You need to share the code which you tried and the error stack from your console.

Comment: It worked , apologies. Thanks for the help