# dropbox cookies on banner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cookies, banner

I'm trying to login to dropbox using python selenium (https://www.dropbox.com/login)
Obviously cookie acceptance is required.

I tried to click on the cookie accept button, but `find_element` doesn't see it.
I also tried to first switch to the cookie banner, but that doesn't work either.

xpath of the cookie banner: `//*[@id="ccpa_consent_banner"]`

xpath of cookie button: `//*[@id="accept_all_cookies_button"]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your XPath expression is correct. But you need to handle the `IFRAME` within which the desired element is located. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75159605/7598774

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause of the issue:** Desired element is located within [IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097405/7598774), you need to switch into it before performing `click()` on <kbd>Accept all</kbd> button.

Assuming you are using PYTHON as your binding language, refer the below code.

**Solution:** Working code with in-line explanation:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

# Below 2 lines will switch driver context into the 2 nested IFRAMES
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='consent-iframe']")))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='ccpa-iframe']")))

# Below line will click on Accept All button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "accept_all_cookies_button"))).click()

# Below line is used to come out of IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I nonetheless seem to have the same kind of issue wiht the "Forward" button. I don't manage dto see if it is nested within an iframe as well.  xpath of the button: '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/button'

Comment: Stick to one issue per question. Create a new question with the exact issue and reproducible steps. This way you will get help from a wider audience.