NoSuchElementException in Selenium with text cell
The code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://commercialisti.it/iscritti")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

casella_testo = driver.find_element("id", "Cap")

The error:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="Cap"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.131); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:

The html:
<input class="form-control" id="Cap" name="Cap" type="text" value="">

I'm not getting why it does not find "Cap"

maybe first check selenium gets from server - driver.page_source - maybe it gets different HTML. You can also check if it is inside <iframe> because it needs driver.switch_to.frame

when I try to visit page https://commercialisti.it/iscritti in web browser then I see Sorry, you have been blocked. You are unable to access commercialisti.it

other idea: some pages add elements when you scroll page (it is lazy loading) and this may need to scroll page in Selenium too

If you notice the HTML of your desired element, it is wrapped inside an IFRAME. See below image.

To interact with any elements within an IFRAME, you need to switch the driver context inside the IFRAME first then perform the required action. Once all the actions are performed you can come out of IFRAME.
Refer working code below:
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://commercialisti.it/iscritti')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Below line with switch into the iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//iframe)[1]"))

# Below 2 lines will locate the desired element and send text "text" into the textbox
casella_testo = driver.find_element("id", "Cap")
casella_testo.send_keys("test")

# Below line will come out of iframe context
driver.switch_to.default_content()

time.sleep(10)

Result:

Few references if it helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097405/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75813942/7598774


This worked, thanks. I have another question if I may ask here. I reached the page that I need, the thing now is that I don't need the html, I need the JSON of the results that I see in the Inspect -> Network -> Go on a specific element -> Preview. Is there a way to get that?

Glad it worked. It's best you create a new question for this, you will get answers from a wider community.
