Selenium Xpath selector: Nothing is printed with find_element for text
In my script, i try to select the pagination number in order to loop through. So, I want to get the text. I tried to print that but nothing is displayed in my terminal. Im new in selenium, thus I don't see What is wrong in my code.
print(driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='pagination']/span[@class='pagination-compteur']").text)

here is the html code.
<div class="pagination">
<span class="disabled previous ">
<span class="icon-lt-arrow-left"></span>
<span class="value">Précédent</span>
</span>
<span id="SEL-compteur" class="pagination-compteur"><strong>Page 1</strong> / 3</span>
<a class="link_pagination next pj-lb pj-link" id="pagination-next" title="Page suivante" href="#" data-pjlb="{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;L3BhZ2VzYmxhbmNoZXMvcmVjaGVyY2hlP3F1b2lxdWk9c3lsdmllJm91PUl2cnklMjBzdXIlMjBTZWluZSUyMCUyODk0MjAwJTI5JmlkT3U9TDA5NDA0MTAwJnF1b2lRdWlJbnRlcnByZXRlPXN5bHZpZSZjb250ZXh0ZT04OEhSaFRSdUNXeTBrJTJCWkhUTjdrVlF4SVNNUm5kTkZzVFg4UGclMkJ5bDBpRSUzRCZwYWdlPTI=&quot;,&quot;ucod&quot;:&quot;b64u8&quot;}" data-pjstats="{&quot;idTag&quot;:&quot;PAGE-SUIV&quot;,&quot;pjscript&quot;:&quot;pa.sendEvent('click.navigation',{'click_chapter1':'LEGACY_CLIC','click_chapter2':'MAPPING_CLIC_LR','click':'PAGE_SUIV',idtag:'{%nom}',site_level2:xtn2});&quot;}"> <span class="value">Suivant</span>
<span class="icon icon-lt-arrow-right"></span>
</a>
</div>


Can you share the URL of the page if it is public? If not, you must edit the question and share the HTML of the page in the form of text.

Your XPath expression looks fine. Refer below few trouble shooting steps you can try:

Check if the desired element is located within an IFRAME. If yes, you need to switch into the IFRAME first, then try to locate and print the desired text. Refer the answers below to know more about iframes

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097405/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75813942/7598774


If there is no IFRAME present, then try using selenium's explicit waits. Refer the code below:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

...

print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pagination']/span[@class='pagination-compteur']"))).text)



